# Logic issue at the end of a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a spreadsheet with a column filled with strings. There are sometimes several instances of one string (I've sorted it though so they're all grouped together) so I've created a macro that looks at the current row in the column, determines if its already been posted in the second worksheet, and if it has, it moves to the next row, if it hasn't it posts it and then moves on.

It works perfectly until the end where it completely ignores the last entry. The last entry is one of the instances where there's several of the same strings so the issue almost definitely isn't that its just ignoring the last row.

It's ignoring the last entry completely no matter how many times it repeats. New to vba so any help appreciated.

```
Sub RCFS()
    Dim ProfCtr As String
    Dim S2FreecellH As Long
    Dim ProfCenCellH As Long

    S2FreecellH = 3
    ProfCenCellH = 2
    ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1).Value = ProfCtr

    While IsEmpty(Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4).Value) = False
        If Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4).Value <> ProfCtr Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1) = ProfCtr
            S2FreecellH = S2FreecellH + 1
            ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)
            ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
        Else
            ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy the unique values in Sheet1 column D to Sheet2 Column A?  If so is there any preexisting data Sheet2 Column A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, your loop needs to still flush the value of `ProfCtr` even when you reached the empty cell. You can make it work by looking ahead one row in your `If` condition (add `+ 1`).

Also included a couple of other improvements:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4).Value)
    If Cells(ProfCenCellH + 1, 4).Value <> ProfCtr Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1) = ProfCtr
        S2FreecellH = S2FreecellH + 1
        ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)
    End If
    ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I have this right

```
    ' Stop when you reach an empty cell
    While IsEmpty(Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4).Value) = False

    ' If the cell's value matches the variable ProfCtr then
    ' ignore it and move to the next row.
    If Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4).Value <> ProfCtr Then

       ' But if it -doesn't- match, then copy the variable
       ' ProfCtr to Sheet 2.
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(S2FreecellH, 1) = ProfCtr

       ' Increment your rows
        S2FreecellH = S2FreecellH + 1

       ' Set the next bit of text to copy
        ProfCtr = Cells(ProfCenCellH, 4)
        ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
    Else
        ProfCenCellH = ProfCenCellH + 1
    End If
```

Shouldn't you be setting `Prof Ctr = Cells(ProfCenCelH, 4)` BEFORE doing the copying over to Sheet2?

Answer (score 0):

trincot has the correct answer.  Here is an alternate technique, using built-in method, that will accomplish the same task.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("D1", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheet2.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
End With
```